# Why aren't the values of X and 0 alternating between button pressess in my Tic Tac Toe game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I recently started working on a Tic Tac Toe game (for practice purposes). I have tried to make it using buttons. Every time I click a button it's text will say either "X" or "0". I have one script:

```
using System;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Xand0Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isX = true;
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;

    public void placeXor0()
    {
        if(isX == true)
        {
            text.text = "X";
            isX = false;
        }else if(isX == false)
        {
            text.text = "0";
            isX = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This script is asigned to every button (9 in total), but the first time I press any button its text says "X". The text will only say "0" if I press that same button again.

What I  want to happen is that the text assigned to a button alternates between "X" and "0" with every click of a button. For example, I first press button 1 and its value is set to X. I then press button 4, and its value is set to 0. I then press button 5 and its values is set to X.

**Why isn't my above code working? How can I make it work?**

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Unity, but what's likely happening here is that each button you assign `Xand0Script` to is getting its own instance of `Xand0Script`.

The least technical way I can explain this is each button has its own copy of `Xand0Script` assigned to it, so clicking one button has no impact on the state of any other buttons copy of `Xand0Script`, including the value of `IsX`.

For example, assume you have two buttons: 1 and 2. Each button gets its own copy of `Xand0Script`. Let's call them `X01` and `X02`. When you click Button 1, `X01.IsX` is set to `False`, but `X02.IsX` still has a value of `True`.

What you need to do is make `IisX` static, like so:

```
public class Xand0Script : MonoBehaviour {
    public static bool isX = true;
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;

    public void placeXor0()
    {
        if(isX == true)
        {
            text.text = "X";
            isX = false;
        }else if(isX == false)
        {
            text.text = "0";
            isX = true;
        }
    } }
```

By making `IsX` static, every instance of `Xand0Script` will be referencing the same instance of `IsX`. In our above example, that means clicking Button 1 results in `IsX` being set to `False` for both `X01` and `X02`.

You can read more about static members [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members).

Answer (score -1):

I am surprised at the answers suggesting to make the field static. Please **do not do that**.

## Why you experience the problem

Assumedly, you have this Xand0Script behaviour attached to each button. Because `isX` is instance, it means that each button has its own verison of `isX`, and it being true in one does not equate to being true in all of them.

## Don't blindly make things `static`!

Others have expressed to make the field static so that the state is shared. But this is not good practice.

Static variables violate a fundamental principle of C# / .NET, which is proper encapsulation and object-oriented practices. Making things static ultimately means you don't care about classes and their state, which begs the question of why even use C#, but I digress.

Equally importantly, static values are also not supported by Unity's serialization system. This is important to be aware of because it means your state *will not persist*, as others wrongly led you to believe otherwise.

## How you should actually do it

You should properly encapsulate and separate behaviour. The code modifying the UI should not at all care whose turn it currently is, it should only care about the UI.

It is common to use a so called `GameManager` to track the state of gameplay, and it's this class that should know whose turn it is. When a move is placed, it should then signal to any relevant behaviour(s) for the grid to update their state and display the player's letter.

You should also use concrete types for defining the possible players, such as:

```cs
enum Player
{
    X,
    O
}
```

Which is when tracked by the GameManager, to know whose turn it is:

```cs
class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Player _currentPlayer;

    public void PlaceMove(int x, int y)
    {
        // set the cell at the specified x and y coordinate
        // to be whatever _currentPlayer is
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You just have to make 'isX' variable static, by doing it so your state is preserved.

```
public static bool isX = true;
```

Comment: This is horrible advice. You shouldn't blindly make things static for no reason.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).